# Could Sai be an Uchiha?

Tags: naruto

I know officially his name is Sai Yamanaka (which could be a lie), but what I'm asking is: could he have Uchiha DNA?

1. Sai was kept underground for the majority of his upbringing and hidden, furthermore within the foundation he mastered the suppression of all emotion, and Tobirama Senju explained the the Sharingan is awakened with extreme emotion.
2. Itachi only had so much time to slaughter the entire bloodline; any Uchiha out on missions may have survived, hidden within the Anbu. And when you are born a Uchiha, you can deactivate the eye. Maybe it's possible there were still Uchiha within the village as part of a 'witness protection' service to keep them hidden. (It's possible that it was being planned for some time and the Anbu Uchiha were pulled out of service, but it's still possible they didn't.)

If both those statements are true, doesn't that mean Sai could be an Uchiha? I haven't started *Boruto*, if this was explored there I don't know, but Sai feels like a side character and I doubt it.

Comment: I feel like your evidence is extremely tenuous.

Comment: Indeed, but it's possible right? ill be honest this is more of a shower thought than anything lol

Comment: With regards to the point about his name "being a lie" that wouldn't be wrong, those of the foundation have no names, Yamato and Sai were both assigned first names just prior to their assignment to Team 7 having been nameless until that point and were never assigned a family name. They both keep those names going forward and when Sai marries Ino of the Yamanaka clan he takes on the name of their clan

Answer (score 3):

...*no*.

Sai was an orphan.  He had no other attachments to anything or any*one* other than Root and Danzo.  If he *were* an Uchiha, surely by now his dojutsu would have been made a prevalent part of the series (along with an attempt by Danzo to steal the eyes).

His full name is the result of him taking the surname of his wife.

Comment: But Sai's whole gimmick was suppressing his emotions. The Sharigan appears after extreme emotions are felt. Furthermore him being an orphan leaves room for his parents to be Uchiha. In context of the show, not telling someone who there parents are isn't that extreme. Naruto didn't even know about Minato for a long time, and he wasn't in the foundation. Im doubting you read the post. And there is room for theory here your just saying what you think you know. be critical

Answer (score 0):

Sai was an orphan. He only had the person he believed to be Shin's brother. Besides, Sai was sincere, direct and cool in personality. He would not broadcast soybeans on the Uchiha, because he did not hate anyone. And in Uchiha, hatred was born easily as Tobirama Senju explained it;)